# how to activate a button when another button is clicked in Obj C equivalent to java .doClick()

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Can someone please elaborate on how to use this `[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` to click a button from within a different button click.

```
  .m
  int i = 0;

- (IBAction)brain:(UIButton *)sender {
   //Brain of the operation
    i++;
   }


- (IBAction)subBrain:(UIButton *)sender {
  if(i > 1){
  /* Here if the brain had been prior clicked then when subBrain is 
  clicked, edit some variables and re-click the brain button 
  how would I go about this?!? Also is there a better way of doing this?*/
  [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  }

  }

   .h
- (IBAction)brain:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)subBrain:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Comment: This seems very odd. So why not try and elaborate on what you want to happen a bit. You have two buttons and you want touches on one to copy to the other?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've used something similar to that in the past, and it worked.  But directly invoking the IBAction method is simpler.  The only reason to not invoke IBAction would be if the touch event mapping is somehow dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, you would usually not try to trigger the other Button in the UI, but trigger the function directly that the Button is attached to.
So in your case, you would call:

```
[self brain:nil]
```

Or better yet, drag the button itself to the .h file and create a new referencing outlet, calling it "brainButton" or something. Than you can refer to "self.brainButton" in the code, and could do something like

```
[self brain:self.brainButton] // if you need the sender
```

Comment: Thank you @LordT !

[self brain:nil]

Worked For What I Needed